# How to get to material nodes 2.8

Tags: node-editor

I Am looking for where to edit my material nodes but I can only find the render nodes. I have been looking for quite some time now. I cant find the material node editor.

This is 2.8
Help?

Comment: It's now called Shader Editor, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Oh duh. THank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender 2.8x you have the option to switch between workspaces for particular tasks. Blender already includes one for creating materials and it is called *Shading*. The workspaces are listed as tabs in the top bar.

[image: Shading workspace tab]

[image: Shading workspace]

The benefit of using/creating workspaces is that you don't have to change the layout, create areas or switch editor types for a particular step of your workflow. Instead you can simply switch to a different workspace that is already prepared for the task.

You can of course still change the editor type like in Blender 2.79 and earlier. The editor for materials is the *Shader Editor*.

[image: Editor Type, Shader Editor]

Comment: Thank you thank you!